# Broken Exchange in AD Environment

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010

One of our testing exchange servers hadn't been used for awhile and when a tech was trying to get it working again (hub transport wouldn't start, SID errors in event log, etc.) he got frustrated and deleted the computer account. We then created a new VM and attempted to install Exchange 2013 on a server 2012 R2. It completed but said that it cannot contact IIS on the (older and now removed) exchange server to load the OAB.

Here is the exact message:
[image]

How can we properly remove the previous exchange information from our domain and install a totally fresh exchange instance?

Comment: Is this the only exchange server on the domain? Clearing up one server and clearing all exchange information is different

Comment: It is/was the only exchange server in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up the exchange information using adsi edit.

Open ADSI Edit to here `CN=Configuration,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL,CN=Services`and delete

```
CN=Microsoft Exchange
CN=Microsoft Exchange Autodiscover
```

Browse to `CN=Default naming context,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL` and delete

```
CN=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups
CN=Microsoft Exchange Security Objects
```

Delete the install folder from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server`

Delete the IIS sites

Delete the following user accounts from active directory

```
DiscoverySearch Mailbox{GUID}
Exchange Online-ApplicationAccount
FederatedEmail.GUID
Migration.GUID
SystemMailbox{GUID}
HealthMailboxGUID
```

In the registry find `HKLM\Software\Microsoft` and delete `ExchangeServer` also find `HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and delete `MSExchange`

You will also need to run the prepare ad command on install