# Issue installing exchange server 2013

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, installation, exchange-2013

I was installing exchange server 2013 on windows server 2012 until, in finalizing installation my PC froze and I reset it.  After that I tried to install it again, but I see this happened:

http://i59.tinypic.com/1t7bf9.png

Looks like next button is disabled what must I do to go forward?

Comment: Is it a fresh install of exchange? or did you already have exchange server and this is an upgrade?

Comment: @drifter104 no this is fresh install

Comment: Have a look at my post on the following thread to clean up a failed exchange install. http://serverfault.com/questions/709185/broken-exchange-in-ad-environment/709196#709196